# Combining (dry) vents for fewer roof penetrations

Tags: plumbing, venting, p-trap

I am remodeling and in the process need to move part of the vent stack. A simplified sketch of my existing plumbing situation across multiple floors is shown (pencil). I am proposing to eliminate vent VT2 that is penetrating the roof and connecting it to another existing vent line VT1 (change shown in pen blue). I will have to slope it down in some parts (which should be OK since each section before and after the hump can drain into its respective downstream drain. The vent will be a dry one so there should be fewer sizing constrains.
[image]

Is there a reason that this might not be allowed? Our [BC plumbing code](https://free.bcpublications.ca/civix/content/public/bcpc2018/938460045/1160030191/?xsl=/templates/browse.xsl) is a little impenetrable for me but I sense that it doesn't object to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them but you MUST have fall back to the sink or vented accessory. In other words, if water enters the vent pipe because of rain or snow, the water cannot collect in a low spot blocking the purpose of the vent. When that criteria is met, I have seen this done in the attic space and the vent size is increased to accommodate the multiple smaller vents tied into it.

Comment: I just seen in the question by the OP is in BC, this is a requirement for the US, as it should be in BC as well, since it will defeat the purpose of the vent if water sets in a low spot of the vent pipe.

Comment: Under the code I mostly know (not BCs - IPC with some local modifications) the vent is supposed to drain back to the line it serves, so even though the "drain both ways" would appear to keep water from collecting, it's not suitable under the code I'm familiar with, which (to my recollection ATM) forbids dumping vent drainage into a different drain - it's all supposed to slope and flow back to the drain that vent serves, until it joins a vent stack. BC might differ, or they might not. If both vents joined and the single penetration came out of the high point, that would pass AFAIR.

Comment: Vent size may also need to increase to prevent the vent freezing, depending what part of BC's wide-ranging weather the house is in.

Comment: We do increase our vents to 3" just before roof penetration to protect against frost blocking the vent. I will have to investigate how the rule of vents only draining into their own drain applies here. Thanks all for answers and comments.

Comment: You may need to combine them at the point where they combine, not where the vent exits. like a 3X2X2 wye or sanitary tee,  or use reducers if needed, whichever is appropriate.